# EKS control plane placed in same VPC with worker node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I checked this [artical](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/containers/de-mystifying-cluster-networking-for-amazon-eks-worker-nodes/) and saw that EKS control plane VPC is not same with worker node VPC. Seem that they are 2 seperated VPCs.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. When I create EKS cluster or Worker Node Group, it is required to select VPC. I can select both of them in same VPC.
   [image]
   But why the artical show me in 2 different VPCs?
2. For EKS control plane, I should put it into public or private subnet for `public and private` network mode?

Answer (score 1):

The VPC you select for cluster creation is for the worker nodes.

As the article explained, the control plane sits in an AWS-managed VPC. This is not one of the VPC you can see in your AWS Account.

Hence, for your second question, it is not possible for you to put the EKS control plane in a public or private subnet. It is managed by AWS.